# is there any way that i can remove the empty spaces being generated by the openai api which my js file returns to the html file?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, openai-api

[code with line breaks] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aOpR.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAg2B.jpg) the response being generated by the openai API shows up like this. As you can see it appends a '<br>' tag or some other kind of line break at the end of each line that makes all these empty spaces but all of it goes away once I refresh the page like here: [code with spaces line breaks removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxYv8.jpg)

the following is an excerpt from the javaScript files that returns the API responses to the HTML file where it shows up in the chat box.

All kind of suggestions and criticisms are welcomed if they helps me solve the problem :)

```
// Display the conversation data in the chat box
if (conversation.length > 1) {
  const messages = conversation.map(message => {
    if (message.sender === 'user') {
      return `
        <div class="message sent ${botMessageClass2}">
          <div class="message-content">
            <div class="sent_t">${message.prompt}
              <p class="text-end time text-muted">${message.time}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
    } else {
      return `
        <div class="message recieved ${botMessageClass}">
          <div class="message-content">
            <div class="recieved_t">
              
            ${message.bot.filter(line => line.trim() !== '').map((line, index) => {
              if (index === 0) {
                // Remove leading whitespace and "A:" prefix from first line
                
                
                return `<p style="margin-bottom:0px;">${line.trim().replace(/^A:\S*/,'')}</p>`;
                
              } else {
                
                console.log(line+"chime");
                return `<p style="margin-bottom:0px;">${line.trim().replace(/^A:\S*/,'')}</p>`;
                
              }
            }).join('<br>')}
              <p class="text-end time text-muted">${message.time}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
    }
  });
  chatBox.innerHTML = messages.join('');
  chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
}
```

i tried using the following lines of code expecting that it would remove the empty spaces or break lines from the chat box:
edit: i suddenly discovered that this solution does work but after i refresh the page :(

```
$('.recieved_t br').remove();
```

`.recieved_t is a div class that contains the para tags containing the responses from the openai's api